# Test for zero mean and variance equal to one

Tags: hypothesis-testing

For one sample, that I don't know its distribution is there a way to test for 
$$H_0: \mu=0  \text{ and }\sigma^2=1.$$

Edit:
My data come from a discrete distribution (Poisson, Binomial) and the probability follows an AR(1) process,

$$Y_t| \pi_t \sim Discrete(\pi_t), $$ where $$h(\pi_t)=\phi_0 +\phi_1h(\pi_{t-1})+\epsilon_t,\ \epsilon_t\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1).$$

In order to assess the overall fit I am trying to implement the method [Normalised log likelihood](http://scholar.harvard.edu/files/bayes.pdf) (page 559).

I have a posterior sample and for each sample I compute the 1-step ahead log likelihood $\mathcal{l}_{t+1} $. Then I simulate values of $f(y_{t+1}|\mathcal{F}_t;\theta)$, compute the 1-step ahead log predictive likelihood function $l^{j}_{t+1}$and evaluate mean and variance. Then $Z_{t+1}=\frac{\mathcal{l}_{t+1}- \mu^{j}_{t+1}}{\sigma^{j}_{t+1}}$ is a variable with zero mean and variance 1 if the model is correct.

So the sample $\{Z_{t+1},\cdots,Z_T\}$ should have zero mean and variance one if the model is correct.

I would like to ask if there is a test for this problem.

Comment: Do you have any distributional assumptions at all? Clearly not the explicit form but symmetry / unimodality etc? Is you variable continuous?

Comment: My data come from a discrete distribution (Poisson, Binomial) and the probability follows an AR(1) process.I have a posterior sample and for each sample I compute the 1-step ahead log likelihood $\mathcal{l}_{t+1} $.Then I simulate values of $f(y_{t+1}|\mathcal{F}_t;\theta)$, compute the 1-step ahead log predictive likelihood function $l^{j}_{t+1}$and evaluate mean and variance.Then $Z_{t+1}=\frac{\mathcal{l}_{t+1}- \mu^{j}_{t+1}}{\sigma^{j}_{t+1}}$ is a variable with zero mean and variance 1 if the model is correct.So the sample $\{Z_{t+1},\cdots,Z_T\}$ should have zero mean and variance one.

Comment: This is potentially important information, but it's a bit hard to follow there. Can you put this information into the question but more clearly describe the background / the underlying problem you're trying to solve here?

Answer (score 3):

Unless you know the parametric form of the distribution (e.g., normal), there is no way to construct a rigorous formal test of the hypothesis using classical methods.

If the sample is large, and if the observations are independent, then there are bootstrap or re-sampling methods that could be used. These would need to be tuned to the nature of your data, which you do not explain in your question.